# Tomcat Rewrite Valve is creating a loop in clientapp

Tags: vue.js, tomcat, url-rewriting, browser-history, server-configuration

I have a Vue SPA with History-mode running in tomcat.
To solve a 404 routing issue i have added this code to my ~/conf/server.xml file in tomcat:

```
 ...
    <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
        unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">

      <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />

 ...
    </Host>
 ...
```

and i have added this code to my ~/Catalina/localhost/rewrite.config  file: (btw i have 6 apis in different containers, i think they are the thing creating the issue maybe?)

```
 RewriteRule ^/api1/ - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/api2/ - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/api3/ - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/api4/ - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/api5/ - [L,NC]
 RewriteRule ^/api6/ - [L,NC]
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
 RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.html
```

I have restarted my server and still i am getting an infinite loop in my arrays that are being populated from my api's.
The issue does not exist if i remove the rewrite.config.
But then i get the 404 error again..
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was solved by changing to this code in the rewrite.config file.

```
   RewriteRule ^/myapi1/.* - [L,NC]
   RewriteRule ^/myapi2/.* - [L,NC]
   RewriteRule ^/myapi3/.* - [L,NC]
   RewriteRule ^/myapi4/.* - [L,NC]
   RewriteRule ^/myapi5/.* - [L,NC]
   RewriteRule ^/host-manager/.* - [L,NC]
   RewriteRule ^/manager/.* - [L,NC]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
   RewriteRule ^/(.*) /index.html
```